# Temporarily allow EC2 instance access to AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-sns, amazon-iam, aws-cloudformation

I am deploying an EC2 instance using CloudFormation and I need to publish information about the created instance to an HTTP endpoint. I plan on doing this using SNS. However, I do not want the instance to have permanent access to publish to the endpoint or be able to use the AWS CLI.

Is there a way to deploy the instance with permission to publish to a specified SNS topic and then rescind permission immediately afterwards?

Comment: How are you triggering CloudFormation? One idea would be to have whatever process triggered CloudFormation to publish the information. The information about the instance could be provided as the `Output` of the CloudFormation stack.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein, Thank you, this has proven helpful

Answer (score 0):

Use IAM ([IAM and Amazon SNS Policies Together)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/UsingIAMwithSNS.html) to create a `SNS Role` which has just enough privileges to publish a specified SNS topic.

Launch the instance and specify the your role as instance's IAM profile

After publishing, remove the SNS privileges from the role using the IAM dashboard or from the instance (make sure the role has privileges to rescind the permission)

Comment: Thanks, I was looking into a similar direction. However, I need the process to be fully automated. Is there a way to do this without having to access the dashboard? Also, when you say remove the privileges, what exactly do you mean? Removing a policy from the role?